# Width = %, Height = Pixel, what type of layout uses percentage and pixel?

Tags: html, css, layout

Simple question but I cant seem to find the answer, sorry about the bad title.

When designing a website can you set the width properties as a percent value and the height properties as a pixel value, in the same layout? If so what type of layout is this called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can and as far as I know there's no formal name for it.

Comment: "can you set the width properties as a percent value and the height properties as a pixel value, in the same layout?" -- sure you can. "If so what type of layout is this called?" -- I'll respond with a question: have you seen it anywhere?

Comment: Thanks and yes I have, I have used this on my first website but I wasn't sure if it was classed as a good or bad technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common practice to do something like this in a responsive layout, but this technique by itself doesn't have a special name. It's only one small part of a responsive layout.

I use this technique frequently for headers where I want the header container to fill the screen horizontally but only take up a fixed space vertically. If you give it a `position: relative` then you can also size the content responsively, so the content can then reflow depending on the width.

Comment: Is there any sense in doing this for images? Images in general don't stretch well.

Comment: You could place images inside a container sized with this technique and the image could scale inside the container, but responsive images is an as-yet-unsolved problem so any solution will have its drawbacks.